# Unable to use Page markup plugin in newer jenkins version

Tags: html, jenkins, plugins

I want to use jenkins plugin called "page markup plugin" for adding a footer content in Jenkins Pages. In newer version of jenkins, the html which we are giving in the footer part inside "configure jenkins", plugin option is not getting rendered in Jenkins Pages. It is showing as html content itself in footers. Please help to resolve the same. I tried many ways, but none help. in older versions this works fine.

tried the CSP disabling, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the page markup plugin is no longer supported and no longer in the [plugin registry](https://plugins.jenkins.io).

Also appears to be a security vulnerability:

[Plugins affected by 2018-10-10 Stapler security hardening](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=164561025#content/view/164561025)

Consider the [Simple Theme plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/simple-theme-plugin) instead.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Yes I also heard the same, but can you please tell me, how to add an html hyperlink using the css? or is there any way to edit the footer and include some hyperlinks to it.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the [Rackspace Canon](https://github.com/rackerlabs/canon-jenkins). It has a custom footer.